# VoIP Push not work for an iOS SDK Demo

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, voip, pushkit

I'm developing an iOS SDK with VoIP PushKit. And here is the code in SDK when receive a push notification

```
- (void)onReceiveMessagecontent:(NSString *)content{    
    if (content && ![content isEqualToString:@""]) {
        if ([[WalkieTalkie sharedWT].delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onPushMessage:)]) {
            [[WalkieTalkie sharedWT].delegate onPushMessage:content];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in SDK Demo MainViewController.m where delegate will be called :

```
- (void)onPushMessage:(NSString *)messageContent{
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"on recive push message: %@", messageContent];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"收到推送" message:content preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *cancelButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"取消" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:cancelButton];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
            notification.alertBody = content;
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        });
    }
}
```

When app is active the UIAlertController works well, but when I kill the app makes it in background mode the UILocalNotification never fire. However I can see some device log from Xcode that prove the remote notification had already been called and run the line of code :`[[WalkieTalkie sharedWT].delegate onPushMessage:content];` in SDK. But the demo app just show nothing, none reaction. Did I put the delegate codes in a wrong place? Or just the SDK is active and app is still in background? I have no idea, please give me some advice, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug app in kill state as well.

Set scheme like below image.

Run app once, it will not come on device, when you tap on icon then it will work only.

So when you run app, actually it will be in kill state, so now fire PushKit Payload and put debug pointer at required place. just debug the app properly you would be able to figure out problem.

[image]